# Type of sentence structure

Tags: sentence-construction, punctuation, commas

The last sentence here – supplemental – what distinguishes it from a sentence that would cause a comma splice?

If I was to write - ***it was*** the most fitting conclusion... it would become a comma splice and need a semi-colon.

> winning his favorite competition, the long jump, and bringing home another Gold Medal for the United States, **the most fitting conclusion to his brilliant career in track and field.**

Source: http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/run-on.htm  (full sentence)

also: would this last sentence take a **dash** instead of a comma? Would either be correct?

Comment: You have not given us a sentence, but a fragment.  If you add **was** after "United states" and remove that comma it would be a sentence. **Winning his ....and bringing .... was the most fitting ....field**.

Comment: If you were to insert **; it was...** the first clause is still only a fragment lacking a finite verb.    A dash between the two clauses would be permissible; then the first clause is a noun-phrase  just hanging out there on the clothesline to dry.

Comment: If it was: John won the competition, the long jump, and brought home another Gold Medal for the United States, the most fitting conclusion to his brilliant career in track and field.  It would need a semi-colon - correct instead of a comma.

Comment: No. That is wrong. You have not understood the last paragraph in my answer. **the most fitting conclusion to his brilliant career in track and field.** is a noun-phrase, a fragment only, not an independent clause with a finite (tensed) verb.

Comment: Would we not class it as an absolute clause as ti has the subject

Comment: **the most fitting conclusion to his brilliant career in track and field**  cannot function as an absolute clause *here* because there is no well-formed main clause which it can stand freely apart from.  Your first chunk, "winning his favorite competition, the long jump, and bringing home another Gold Medal for the United States" lacks a finite verb.  You could say *He won his favorite competition, the long jump, and brought home another Gold medal for the United States—a most fitting conclusion to his brilliant career in track and field.*

Answer (score 3):

> Winning his favorite competition, the long jump, and bringing home
>   another Gold Medal for the United States—it was the most fitting
>   conclusion to his brilliant career in track and field.

That is OK. It's comparable to *Passing the Bar exam—that was his goal*.

> Winning his favorite competition, the long jump, and bringing home
>   another Gold Medal for the United States was the most fitting
>   conclusion to his brilliant career in track and field.

That is OK too. This syntax is the simpler of the two. Subject + predicate.  *Passing the Bar exam was his goal*.

> Winning his favorite competition, the long jump, and bringing home
>   another Gold Medal for the United States;  it was the most fitting
>   conclusion to his brilliant career in track and field.

That is not OK.  **Winning ... States** is not an independent clause. Each piece of a sentence (not a list) separated by semicolons must be able to stand independently as a finite clause.  *Passing the Bar exam; it was his goal.* NO.